# Multiple delimiters while using ActsAsTaggableOn gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, acts-as-taggable-on

I am using `ActsAsTaggableOn` gem. How do I specify multiple delimiters for a tag list?
I tried:

```
ActsAsTaggableOn::TagList.delimiter = [',', ' ', '\|']
```

But this gives an error:

```
ActionView::Template::Error (undefined method `ends_with?' for [",", " ", "\\|"]:Array)
```

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: According to its README, you should set `ActsAsTaggableOn.delimiter`. And it should accept an array.

Comment: @Sergio I have tried that as well but it gives me an error "in `<top (required)>': undefined method `delimiter=' for ActsAsTaggableOn:Module (NoMethodError)". I don kno if I am doing something wrong

Comment: I was getting that error because I was using older version of the gem(2.2.2). I fixed the problem by using the latest version. Thanks:)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just set `ActsAsTaggableOn.delimiter = [',', ' ', '\|']`

See here for more: https://github.com/mbleigh/acts-as-taggable-on#configuration

Comment: that gives me an error 'in `<top (required)>': undefined method `delimiter=' for ActsAsTaggableOn:Module (NoMethodError)'. I dont know if I am doin something wrong.

Comment: As I have mentioned in my earlier comment, I fixed the error by using the latest version of the gem. Thanks for your help:)